# read xml file and extract some integer value

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have xml file with content like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<REPLY>
  <DATA BYTE='116' />
  <DATA BYTE='88' />
  <DATA BYTE='15' />
  <DATA BYTE='0' />
from this
  <DATA BYTE='44' />  
  <DATA BYTE='1' />
  <DATA BYTE='0' />
  <DATA BYTE='0' />
to this
  <DATA BYTE='0' />
  <DATA BYTE='0' />
.....
  <DATA BYTE='255' />
  <DATA BYTE='255' />
  <DATA BYTE='255' />
  <DATA BYTE='0' />
</REPLY>
```

I want to read 4 lines from this to this, actually I want to extract values `44`,`1`,`0`,`0` from these 4 lines. Values are dynamic, structure of document will not change (at least in first 15 lines).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: close vote! please elaborate why.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but its not clear how you determine what lines to read.  Do you want to read just lines 5-8?  That's what I *think* you want, but it's not 100% clear.

Comment: sorry for that, I want to read only this 4 lines from line 5 to 8.

Comment: I also didn't vote to close I know it's requirement but you should be clear without any identification how can you retrieve a specific value.

Comment: Still think that question is pretty clear, it has note inside question body and exact value which I want to extract from file content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Load your XML into `XDocument` instance using `XDocument.Parse()` or `XDocument.Load()` methods.
2. Query your XML using LINQ to XML:

```
var values = doc.Root.Elements("DATA").Skip(4)
                                      .Take(4)
                                      .Select(x => (int)x.Attribute("BYTE"))
                                      .ToList();
```

I assumed that `REPLY` is a root element in your XML. If it's not, you have to query for it first:

```
var reply = doc.Descendants("REPLY").First();
var values = reply.Elements("DATA").Skip(4)
                                   .Take(4)
                                   .Select(x => (int)x.Attribute("BYTE"))
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: you can use LastAttribute.value

Comment: @DhavalPatel Yes, it could be slightly better, but I think it would also be less readable.